# Preload Text from an External site

Tags: actionscript-3, url, loader

I am using this actionscript multiple times within a document:

```
var loader1:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("http:url.com/example.txt"));
loader1.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
var loadedText1:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
Box.text = loadedText1.data;
}
```

Unfortunately, there tends to be a significant lag in terms of this text appearing. How can I get flash to cache these text files before it called upon to display them? -- kinda like a pre loader for text files.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rudimentary loading queue, which will take a vector of URL strings, and download then store the text from them in sequence, then notify you when they're all done. After that point you can access the stored text at any point.

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var urls:Vector.<String> = new <String>["ex1.txt", "ex2.txt", "ex3.txt"]; //Add all your URLs here
var loadedText:Vector.<String> = new <String>[]; //Your text will be stored here
var queuePos:int = 0;
var textLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
textLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, text_load);
this.addEventListener("TEXT_LOADED", text_display);

text_load(); //This is called to start the loading process

function text_load(event:Event=null):void {
    if (queuePos > 0) loadedText.push(textLoader.data); //Store the last received text

    if (queuePos >= urls.length) { //Stop the queue if all complete
        textLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, text_load);
        dispatchEvent(new Event("TEXT_LOADED"));
        return;
    }

    textLoader.load(new URLRequest(urls[queuePos])); //Load the next URL
    queuePos++;
}

function text_display(event:Event):void { //Called once all text has been loaded
    Box.text = loadedText[0]; //Adds text from the 1st URL to the Box TextField
    Box2.text = loadedText[1]; //Adds text from the 2nd URL, etc.
}
```

So this allows you first of all to do all your external loading at once. And after you've let it run once, you can grab any of the stored text snippets from the `loadedText` vector, at any time. e.g. `Box.text = loadedText[0];` to load text from the first URL in the `urls` vector, and so on.

As a side note, it can make life easier to have your external content contained in a single **XML** or **JSON** file, both of which are well supported in Flash. This lets you divide the text snippets you need into separate variables inside one file, reducing the number of load requests needed. Of course, you might not have control over the specific content you're retrieving, and in that case it wouldn't apply. But if you're the content author, I'd recommend looking into these.